# Invalid CFML construct error with Simple ColdBox Application

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

I want to make a simple ColdBox application. So I used the instructions in [this link](http://www.cfframeworks.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/2/26/Installing-the-Coldbox-Framework-in-two-easy-steps) and downloaded [coldbox_3.5.2](http://www.coldbox.org/download). But when I try to view this url in my browser:

```
 http://127.0.0.1/coldbox_3.5.2/samples/
```

I am getting following error :

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 28 at column 22.

ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
{

The CFML compiler was processing:

A script statement beginning with this.flash on line 28, column 9.
A cfscript tag beginning on line 12, column 2.
```

As I am trying this for the first time, I have no idea what is causing the error. Can anyone help me understand the error?

Comment: What is the version of CF you are using?

Comment: is it 8 or 8.01? As per coldbox doc, it needs 8.01 http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Installation.cfm

Comment: in the administrator version its written 8,0,0,176276  ..this is 8 only?

Comment: Thanks it worked , i upgradedd my cf version to 9 and also renamed the folder coldbox3.5.2 to coldbox..

Comment: To make this question is closed, I will add my comment as answer. Please accept it. It will give some points to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because CF8 (build 8,0,0,176276) did not support nested inline structs.

As per its requirements, ColdBox needs CF 8.0.1 (build 8,0,1,195765) or above.

http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Installation.cfm