# Invalid CFML construct found

Tags: coldfusion, components, coldbox

i have coldfusion8, windows7. i have installed **ColdBox** version "coldbox_3.5.3" on wwwroot of my coldfusion. when i am trying to run  **`http://localhost:8500/coldbox/samples/`**
i am getting error-

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 28 at column 22.

ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
{

The CFML compiler was processing:

A script statement beginning with this.flash on line 28, column 9.
A cfscript tag beginning on line 12, column 2.

The error occurred in C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\coldbox\system\web\config\Settings.cfc: line 28
Called from C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\coldbox\system\web\loader\FrameworkLoader.cfc: line 51
Called from C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\coldbox\system\web\Controller.cfc: line 43
Called from C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\coldbox\system\Coldbox.cfc: line 69
Called from C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\coldbox\samples\Application.cfc: line 35
26 : 
27 :    // flash scope defaults
28 :    this.flash = {
29 :        scope = "session",
30 :        properties = {},
```

how to solve this error?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid CFML construct error with Simple ColdBox Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138168/invalid-cfml-construct-error-with-simple-coldbox-application)

Comment: can you expand this and show us the statements before and after the one starting on line 28. There's a syntax error somewhere, but it's not in the code in the error message.