# How to install and test wirebox 1.6?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfml, coldbox

I am using ColdFusion8, Windows7 64 bit OS, and I have downloaded Wirebox 1.6 from [ColdBox](http://www.coldbox.org/download). I have extracted the files and placed them in `wwwroot` and created a "index.cfm" page with the code below:

```
<cfscript>
  wirebox = createObject("component","wirebox.system.ioc.Injector").init();
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#wirebox#">
```

But it is throwing an error:

> ```
> Invalid CFML construct found on line 43 at column 36.
> ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
> {
> The CFML compiler was processing:
> A script statement beginning with instance on line 43, column 25.
> A cfscript tag beginning on line 33, column 18.
> A cfscript tag beginning on line 33, column 18.
>
> The error occurred in C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\wirebox\system\ioc\Injector.cfc: line 43
> 41 : 
> 42 :          // Prepare Injector instance
> 43 :          instance = {
> 44 :              // Java System
> 45 :              javaSystem = createObject('java','java.lang.System'),
> ```

How do I install it correctly and test the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Installation.cfm), ColdBox requires one of the following engines:

- ColdFusion 8.01 or above
- Railo 2.0 or above
- Open Blue Dragon (not all features are supported)

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138168/invalid-cfml-construct-error-with-simple-coldbox-application/12139430#12139430) explains, CF 8 does not support the nested inline structs which ColdBox uses.

Answer (score 1):

What updater for CF8 are you using?  I'm guessing it's a CF8 bug with `struct` literal parsing.  You could test this by rewriting the `struct` literal to the old-school style:

```
instance = structnew();
instance.javaSystem = createObject(...);
```

Comment: stil i am getting same error saying "Invalid CFML construct found". i have used-<cfscript>
instance = structnew();
instance.javaSystem = createObject("component","wirebox.system.ioc.Injector").init();
</cfscript>

Comment: I would guess there are still other struct literals in the code which are not compatible with your version of CF8.  I would recommend installing the latest CF8 updater.